How to resolve issue while implementing Auto Update in my app
I'm trying to implement auto update in my app. So the approach i followed is to host a json file on server, and retrieve the json file to compare the version code with app code to check if there is any update available. I'm successfully retrieving if there is any update, and i'm able to download the updated APK from server. The problem i am facing is while installing the apk. My app crashes after the download is completed.
Here is my code.
package com.android.launcher3.network

import android.app.Dialog
import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import app.lawnchair.util.Constants
import com.android.launcher3.BuildConfig
import com.android.launcher3.R
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import kotlinx.coroutines.DelicateCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.io.File
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
fun checkSelfUpdate(context: Context, applicationContext: Context) {
    val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT).create()
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Log.i("Updates", "Checking for Updates")
        val response = HttpClient.getPreferredClient().get(Constants.UPDATE_URL, mapOf())
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.i("Updates", "Checking for Updates after successful response")
                val selfUpdate = gson.fromJson(
                    String(response.responseBytes),
                    SelfUpdate::class.java
                )

                selfUpdate?.let {
                    Log.i("Updates", "Checking for Updates " + it.versionCode)
                    if (it.versionCode > BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE) {
                        if (it.auroraBuild.isNotEmpty()) {
                            showUpdatesSheet(it, context, applicationContext)
                            Log.i("Updates", "Update Founded")
                            Toast.makeText(context, "New updates available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        } else {
                            Log.i("Updates", "No Update Founded in aurora build")
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No updates available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i("Updates", "No Update Founded")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Updates", "Failed to check self update: ${response.code}")
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun showUpdatesSheet(
    selfUpdate: SelfUpdate,
    context: Context,
    applicationContext: Context
) {

    val dialog = Dialog(context)
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.setCancelable(true)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_updates)

    val yesBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.positive_button_update) as Button
    yesBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(selfUpdate.auroraBuild))
        
        // Set other request options
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
        val url = selfUpdate.auroraBuild
        val potentialFilename: String = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)

        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
            potentialFilename
        )
        request.setTitle("New Version Found")
        request.setDescription("Downloading...")
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)

        val download_Id = downloadManager.enqueue(request) // Remember the download ID

        val broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                val downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1L)
                if (downloadId == download_Id) {
                    // Download complete, open the downloaded file
                    openDownloadedApk(applicationContext)
                    applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(this) // Unregister after handling the intent
                }
            }
        }

        applicationContext.registerReceiver(
            broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE),
            Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED
        )

        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    val noBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.negative_button_update) as TextView
    noBtn.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    dialog.show()

}

private fun openDownloadedApk(context: Context) {
    val downloadedApk = File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
        "Latest_app.apk"
    )

    if (downloadedApk.exists()) {
        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider",
            downloadedApk
        )

        if (contentUri != null) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
                setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            }

            try {
                Log.d("Installation", "Starting APK installation")
                context.startActivity(intent)
                Log.d("Installation", "APK installation started successfully")
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                Log.e("Installation", "Activity not found to handle the intent: ${e.message}")
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                Log.e(
                    "Installation",
                    "Security exception: User might not have granted permission to open file.",
                    e
                )
                // Inform user about permission requirement and guide them to settings
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("Installation", "Error opening downloaded APK: ${e.message}")
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Installation", "Failed to create content URI for downloaded APK")
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Download", "Downloaded APK not found")
    }
}


Here is my logs after crash.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: app.lawnchair.debug, PID: 20531
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=app.lawnchair.debug (has extras) } in com.android.launcher3.network.CheckSelfUpdateKt$showUpdatesSheet$1$broadcastReceiver$1@fef8dd6
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$android-app-LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1800)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority app.lawnchair.debug.provider
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getFileProviderPathsMetaData(FileProvider.java:664)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:695)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:645)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:449)
                                                                                                        at com.android.launcher3.network.CheckSelfUpdateKt.openDownloadedApk(checkSelfUpdate.kt:168)
                                                                                                        at com.android.launcher3.network.CheckSelfUpdateKt.access$openDownloadedApk(checkSelfUpdate.kt:1)
                                                                                                        at com.android.launcher3.network.CheckSelfUpdateKt$showUpdatesSheet$1$broadcastReceiver$1.onReceive(checkSelfUpdate.kt:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$android-app-LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1790)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
2024-04-03 01:31:18.997 20531-20531 Process                 app.lawnchair.debug                  I  Sending signal. PID: 20531 SIG: 9

I have tried to add provider tag in manifest. But as i don't have any class in which i'm using fileProvider, so i was unable to add class name in there.
